# how to add condition in object declaration ? EF -

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I would like to do something like this (below)... I don't want to full write out  template.title = xxx, template.descrption =xxx etc.

but I can't compile, because condition is not correct. I seems to be I can add the condition  like this
(lang == "E") ? doctype = "Spot-II: " : doctype = "Spot-IIII "  within the declaration

etc...

Does someone know how to get (lang=="E") condition working below?

```
        foreach (var item in s)
        {
            template = new RSSTemplate()
            {
                title = item.titre,
                description = item.description,
                (lang == "E") ? doctype = "Spot-II: " : doctype = "Spot-IIII "
            };
            t.Add(template);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will work:

```
  foreach (var item in s) 
    { 
        template = new RSSTemplate() 
        { 
            title = item.titre, 
            description = item.description, 
            doctype = (lang == "E") ? "Spot-II: " : "Spot-IIII " 
        }; 
        t.Add(template); 
    }
```